# Kohana 3 Auth database schema

Tags: kohana, kohana-3.2

I just started to learning Kohana 3.2.
It's nice, and it's similar to django so it is going pretty well.
Bad the documentation is... poor.
And the documentation for an Auth module doesn't exist (i'm not talking about this in userguide because that is pooooor). 
I want to use ORM, store users info in database. This should be simple!
But.. I can't even find how database table structure should look like :(

Is there any good doc for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to enable both Auth and ORM in your bootstrap.
Then you need to tell Auth to use ORM. Go to modules/auth/config/auth.php and change `'driver'       => 'file'` to `'driver' => 'ORM'`.
Table schema can be found in modules/orm folder.
You can find more usefull information [here](http://jdstraughan.com/post/auth-module-for-kohana-31-using-orm-driver) (it's for 3.1 but the differences are not that big).